How do we pass instance variable as an argument to instance method in python?
I am trying to pass the self.__kmer_size, which is an instance variable, as an argument to the get_kmer_list method, but getting some error. How do I pass a variable as an argument of a method?
class SequencePreprocessor:

    def __init__(self, kmer_size:int=2, overlapping_kmer:bool=True):
        self.__kmer_size = kmer_size
        self.__overlapping_kmer = overlapping_kmer
    
    def get_kmer_list(self, seq:str, kmer_size:int=self.__kmer_size, overlapping:bool=self.__overlapping_kmer) -> list[str]:


why would you need to? just use it directly, or are you suggesting that as a default?

This can not work. The def line is evaluated only once when the class is created and no instance of it can exist. So, there can not be a self at that point.

TLDR: use None as the default value in the parameter defintion, and an if statement inside your method: if parameter is None: paramter = self.__parameter

no, you aren't trying to pass it as an argument, you are trying to use it when you are defining the default value of a parameter. But there is no self there.
